# Apple Mail save search function not working

Tags: mail.app, search

It used to be easy to save a mail search as a smart mailbox. After Monterey they changed the user interface. Now when you do a search a "Save Search" button appears. But it is always dimmed out and cannot be used.

So am I missing something here, or does it just not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had this problem. In my case I had the `All Inboxes` virtual folder selected. When I changed it to a specific account or folder then the option appeared.

Another way to add a saved search is to just create a smart mailbox with those search terms (Smart Mailboxes in the folder panel)

EDIT

As noted in the comments, this is a workaround. To complete the workaround, you must unselect the condition for which mailboxes the results will be in.

Comment: I just tried some things based on your suggestion. Generally I would want to search All Mailboxes. When All Mailboxes is selected however, you cannot save the search. But if you select a specific mailbox, then you can save the search. Unfortunately, that seems to defeat the purpose of a many searches, in that you would often want to search everywhere. Not sure yet if the search you create in fact does search everywhere once All Mailboxes is not selected. But it is an interesting although odd workaround, to change to a specific mailbox. Will have to test it out for a bit.

Comment: I am going to give credit for this answer. It is in effect a workaround I believe for a strange bug in the Mail program. That is, a search cannot be saved if "All Mailboxes" is selected. To complete the workaround, you have to uncheck the condition for the mailbox, so that all mailboxes can be searched. So it is an odd workaround, but it seems to work.